# How can I assign a value to a property of only a specific element in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and assigned their properties and values using `Array.prototype.fill()`. I want to assign a new value to a property of a specific element in the array.

For example:

```
let data = Array(3).fill({test_1: 0, test_2: true});

function f(index) {
    data[index].test_1 = 5;
    console.log(data);
}

f(0);
```

However, instead of assigning that value to that specific object's property, all of the objects in the array have their own property assigned that same value.

Here is the output:

```
// Actual result
[
 {
  test_1: 5,
  test_2: true
 },
 {
  test_1: 5,
  test_2: true
 },
 {
  test_1: 5,
  test_2: true
 }
];

// Expected result
[
 {
  test_1: 5,
  test_2: true
 },
 {
  test_1: 0,
  test_2: true
 },
 {
  test_1: 0,
  test_2: true
 }
];
```

Instead of only the first object getting 5 as its value for the `test_1` property, all three objects have 5 as their value for their `test_1` properties.

So, my questions are:

- Why is `f()` assigning the same value to the same property of all the elements in the array?
- How can I assign a value to a property of only a specific element of the array?

Comment: You are passing an Object to `fill`, so `fill` will put that exact object at every index. They're all references to the only Object you created

Comment: "*all three objects have 5 as their value*" - no, there is only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `Array.fill` unless you want to fill it with primitive types.

By this `let data = Array(3).fill({test_1: 0, test_2: true})` you passing same object every time, so your array contains 3 times same object, then if you modifying any element of array, in fact it's the same object modified by reference. To avoid it use `Array.from` syntax combined with map callback. Like this:

```js
let data = Array.from({length: 3},  _ => ({test_1: 0, test_2: true}))

function f(index) {
    data[index].test_1 = 5;
    console.log(data);
}

f(0)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone points to the same address in memory, a change of one of them will also cause a change of the others.

This should work:

```js
let data = [...Array(3)].map(() => ({ test_1: 0, test_2: true }));

function f(index) {
    data[index].test_1 = 5;
    console.log(data);
}

f(0);
```